# Don't know how to Correct : "In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same."

Tags: matlab, for-loop, error-handling

I saw other topics about this error but I couldn't figure it out. The error "In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same" occurs at the second for loop. How can I change my code to avoid this error?

```
h1 = [70 31.859 15 5.774 3.199 2.15 1.626];
h2 = [31.859 15 5.774 3.199 2.15 1.626 1.415];
b = [1253 1253 1253 1253 1253 1253 1253];
R = [455.4 425.6 377.6 374.9 371.3 273.7 268.3];
r = [0.5448714286 0.5291754292 0.6150666667 0.4459646692 0.3279149734 0.2437209302 0.1297662977];
k = [200 200 200 200 200 200 200];
s = sqrt(r/(1-r));
v2 = [20 0 0 0 0 0 0];
v1 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
Ch1 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
Ch2 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
C = [100 100 100 100 100 100 100];

F = b .* k .* sqrt(R-(h1-h2))- R.*sin((acos((R-((h1-h2)./2))./R))) .* (pi/2) .* (1./sqrt(r./(1-r))) .* (atan(sqrt(r./(1-r))))-(pi/4) - (1./(sqrt(r./(1-r)) .* sqrt(h2./R))).* log((h2+R.*((sqrt(h1./R).*tan(1/2 .* atan(sqrt(r./(1-r)).*sqrt(h1./r).*log(1./(1-k))))).^2).*sqrt(1-r))./h2)


M = -R.*R.*(k./2).*(.2*(sqrt(h2./R)*tan(0.5*(atan(s)))-(pi/8).*sqrt(h2./R).*log(1./1-r)))-(acos((R-((h1-h2)./2))./R))


    for i=1:6
       v1(i) = ((v2(i)*h2)/h1);
       v2(i+1) = v1(i);
    end


    vr = ((v1.*h1)./h2)./(((tan(0.5.*((atan(s)))-(pi/8).*sqrt(h2./R).*log(1./(1-r)))).^(2))+1)

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Calculating E

w = (((2.*R.*h2).^(3/2))./(300.*(b.^2)))

if (w <= (3*10^-4));
    E = ((0.0821.*((log(w))^2))+(1.25.*log(w))+4.89)
end

if ((3*10^-4)<= w <= (2.27*10^-3));
    E = ((0.0172.*((log(w)).^2))+(0.175.*log(w))+0.438)
end

if (w > (2.27*10^-3))
    E = 0.01
end   

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Calculating Ch:

y = ((((2.*R).^(0.5)).*((h2).^(1.5)))./(b.^2))

N1 = (0.5-(1/pi).*atan((log(y)+8.1938)./(1.1044)))

N = ((h2./h1).*N1)

   for i=1:1;7
       Ch2(i) = (h2.*((N.*((Ch1(i)./h2)-(C./h2)))+(C/h2)))
       Ch1(i+1) = Ch2(i)
    end

DeltaStrain = (E.*((Ch2./h2)-(Ch1./h1)))

if DeltaStrain > 0;
    Stepp = ((2/pi).*(sqrt(DeltaStrain))))
Control = 2;
else 
    Stepp = ((2/pi).*(sqrt(-DeltaStrain))
Control = 0;
end
```

Comment: It is probably happening because `Ch2(i)` is expecting one element, but you are giving it an array or vector. This is what the error is saying - the parts you are trying to put into `i` must have the same shape as `i`. In your case, `i` is a single element.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
       Ch2(i) = (h2.*((N.*((Ch1(i)./h2)-(C./h2)))+(C/h2)))
```

`h2` is a vector, and `Ch2(i)` is a scalar. You cannot assign the value of a vector to a scalar.  I suspect you want to replace the entire `for` loop. Right now you have

```
for i=1:1;7
   Ch2(i) = (h2.*((N.*((Ch1(i)./h2)-(C./h2)))+(C/h2)))
   Ch1(i+1) = Ch2(i)
end
```

(?? what is the meaning of `1:1;7`? Is that a typo? I am thinking you want `1:7`...

Since you seem to be using the result of one loop to change the value of Ch1 which you are using again in the next loop, it may be tricky to vectorize; but I wonder what you are expecting the output to be, since you really do have a vector as the result of the RHS of the equation. I can't be sure if you want to compute the result for one element at a time, or whether you want to compute vectors (and end up appending results to `Ch1` and `Ch2`). The following line would run without throwing an error - but it may not be the calculation you want. Please clarify what you are hoping to achieve if this is an incorrect guess.

```
for i = 1:7
  Ch2(i) = h2.*(N.*((Ch1(i) - C(i))./h2(i))) + C(i)./h2(i);
  Ch1(i+1) = Ch2(i);
end
```